# Cannot select a new <tr> after append

Tags: jquery, clone, appendto

I try to clone a row and then append it as below :-

```
codeTable.$("tr:first").clone().appendTo(codeTable);
```

The code successfully clones and appends the `<tr>` element.
But when I try to select with Jquery, the new element is not included
on the result.

```
codeTable.$('tr');
```

Comment: what is `codeTable`? And obviously your syntax is wrong!!

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
codeTable.find("tr:first").clone().appendTo(codeTable);
```

and to get `tr`:

```
$(codeTable).find('tr');
```

or

```
$('tr', codeTable);
```

Where I assume `codeTable` is jQuery object. If not then wrap it within `$()` like `$(codeTable)`.

Comment: @wajatimur you've to seach after append operation. If possible then make a fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net